# comparing a password md5 php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to compare the value of the password stored in the database (which is done by `md5($mypassword)`), but every time I enter a different password than what is in the DB it still allows me to auth the user... I've tried:

```
$rslt['password'] = md5($mypassword)
$rslt['password'] == md5($mypassword)
$rslt['password'] === md5($mypassword)
```

but neither of them seem to work.

---

a snippet of the code is below:

```
if((mysql_num_rows($qry)==1)&&($rslt['username']==$myusername)&&($rslt['password'] == md5($mypassword)))
    {
    echo $rslt['username'];
    echo $myusername;
    echo $rslt['password'];
    echo md5($mypassword);
    //$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    //$_SESSION['user'] = $rslt['username'];
    //header("location: ../acct_beta.php");
    }
```

any ideas would be helpful. thanks :D

Comment: Well, what do you get if you echo the database record and the output of `md5`?

Comment: if `$myusername` comes directly from $_POST, make sure that magic_quotes is not enabled. The extra backslashes in there will generate a completely different md5 hash value.

Comment: If you're trying also this $rslt['password'] = md5($mypassword) to **compare** you should really think about to study php basis.

Comment: all of the echo's are the same if i put the correct username/password combo and if i put in a different value for the password the last two echos are different

Comment: put the echos outside the if branch and see if they match

Comment: wow @AurelioDeRosa I'm just learning it now.... i thought that this was supposed to be a learning forum. thanks for your helpful input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the logic around a bit and let mysql do the comparison by using

```
select count(*) from <table> where username = @username and password = MD5(@password)
```

If the count > 0  then it's authenticated.

Comment: This is somewhat dangerous, in case he doesn't own the root access to the current server. Host can read all user's password attempts..

Comment: @genesis: only if the binary log is enabled.

Comment: @Marc I have normal general log which shows all queries, even like these.

Comment: @genesis: I know, but it's just an example of an other way to do the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `$mypassword` and/or `$myusername` isn't taken from user's input. Make sure you're not hardcoding these variables and try again

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to put something in: $mypassword=$_POST['passoword'] and $myusername=$_post['username']

Comment: so was this the reason ? is the problem solved? if yes then please accept the answer.

Comment: Ok i figured it out... my actual query in php was flawed... fixt it.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't escaping my query string...